# How to disable Android Studio splash screen?

Tags: android-studio

Every time I start Android Studio on my Linux computer (running Ubuntu), it loads quite a while and overlays at least 1/6 of my screen and it does not minimize, go to background or anything.

How can I either disable the loading splash screen or how to make it possible to allow the loading splash screen to be put in background? It's seriously annoying.

Comment: How can the developers of this crap not address this, boggles the mind. Thank you for your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass "nosplash" in the command-line:

```
android-studio/bin/studio.sh nosplash
```

Works with IntelliJ as well.

Comment: Awesome. One can only wonder why the splash screen in the first place.

Comment: Doesn't work any more...